# HDD exfat partition will not mount

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 dual booted with windows 7 (on separate SSDs) and just stored all of my music on my 1.5 TB HDD (which is formatted as an exfat partition). Everything was working fine for a week or so when earlier today Ubuntu froze up on me twice in a row (it only happens when I open Mixxx) and forced me to restart the computer via the restart button. after this occurred Ubuntu would no longer mount my HDD, when I try I just get this error message:

> Error mounting /dev/sda at /media/mrshafter/Gooch: Command-line `mount -t "exfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,umask=0077" "/dev/sda" "/media/mrshafter/Gooch"' <exited with non-zero exit status 1:
>   stdout:`FUSE exfat 1.0.1
>   '
>   stderr: `ERROR: invalid VBR checksum 0xc7b1f178 (expected 0x61b1f182).
>   '

Is there an easy way to fix this other than reformatting my HDD? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think the free ExFAT file system checker can repair any serious issues. The best way would be to try to fix the file system in Windows which does have a more powerful checker. After all, Microsoft developed ExFAT.

Answer (score 0):

Ehhh, never reboot like that.  You likely corrupted your HDD, and you need to run this at the command line:

```
sudo fsck -a /dev/sda
```

If that runs and output no errors then your HDD is OK.  If it outputs errors, then it should automatically attempt to fix them.  If it can, all should be well.

If it didn't output any errors and still doesn't work, then please let me know and I will help you address the situation in comments below.

Comment: Exact same problem here on a SD card in a failing phone. Now can't read it on Linux. fsck also gives "invalid VBR checksum"...